# seahorse cannot create Password Keyring in Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: password, keyrings, seahorse

After update Ubuntu 23.04 seahorse not working for create new Password Keyring.

I try for:

- move `~/.local/share/keyring` to another name, but not working and don't have action for create password keyring.
- reinstall seahorse

[image: create password keyring]

[image: password keyring]